# Mensaje undefined al pasar como parámetro el indice del grid principal seleccionado en un Nested jqxGrid

Tags: c#, json, asp.net

Hola comunidad alguien sabe porque me sale este error si solo estoy tratando de pasar el id de la tabla seleccionada como parámetro.

Este es mi mensaje de error.

```
{"Message":"undefined no es un valor válido para Int32.","StackTrace":"   en System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToType(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.Exception"}
```

Este es mi webMethod en asp.net c#.

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string ListaPersona(int id_persona)
    {
        Transacciones t = new Transacciones();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = t.Listar_Personas(id_persona);
        string datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);            
        return datos;
    }
```

este es parte de mi ajax.

```
if (id_persona != 0) {            
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "frmPersonas.aspx/ListarPeronas",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{id_persona:"' + resultado + '"}', // Aqui es donde el id de mi fila seleccionada
```

Aquí es donde obtengo el id

```
$('#grid').on('rowclick', function(event) {
                Record = $('#grid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', event.args.rowindex);
                resultado = Record.id_Bonos;

                });
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.Gracias.

Comment: Pero si pones eso siempre vas a pasar el valor 0 como dato. ¿No quieres que se pase otro valor también?

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro Efectivamente necesito pasar otro valor diferente.¿Tendras alguna idea?

Comment: Lo primero una recomendación: no pongas esto como respuesta porque otros usuarios van a pensar que encontraste la solución y van a pasar de largo cuando realmente aún hace falta ayuda. Es mejor que edites la pregunta para añadir esta información. Y cuando la edites, añade algo más de datos: cómo es el html o dónde está el JS puede ser importante para resolver el problema, porque parece que asignas resultado en un sitio pero luego no lo puedes leer en otro. Es posible que sea por el ámbito de la variable.